# How to Configure codeigniter app on ngnix server

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I want to configure my codeigniter application on my Ngnix web server, As it was running perfect on apache server.

I've followed the below links, but All the time it's giving 502 bad gateway error.

https://gist.github.com/lynxluna/1050850

http://www.nginxtips.com/codeigniter-nginx-configuration/

https://gist.github.com/stefan-vatov/4451834

[nginx codeigniter 502 bad gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728010/nginx-codeigniter-502-bad-gateway)

I have my application in `/var/www/example`

And i created the virtualhost file in `/etc/ngnix/sites-enabled/example` and it contains the code below

```
server {
    listen       8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name  example;

    root   /var/www/example;
    index index.php  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
    root /var/www/example;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
                break;
        }
    }
    location ~ \.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
    }
}
```

If i run this on browser localhost:8080 It's throwing an error please can anyone help me to get this out??

Comment: Which error is thrown? Please tell us, so we can further investigate :-)

Comment: When i refresh the page, it's giving 502 bad gateway error.