# set_userdata data gives 502 bad gateway error while using NGINX

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, session

I am using CodeIgniter 3.1 and NGINX server as live and Apache server as local,
my project is running smoothly on Apache local server, but it not doing well on NGINX server Live.
on live its work fine but apparently when i open a page who's code contain lots of set_userdata, like  i have many pages having tables and that tables have filter and in filters I uses set_userdata.
when these function try's to set data for filter it gives error "502 Bad Gateway" nginx.

```
function stats()
{

        $userId = $this->uri->segment(4);
        
    $clientCompanyId = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $checkUser = false;
    
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterStatusNameShow','');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterStatusId', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterStatusName', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pWon', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterClientAccount', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterBusinessType', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterAccountsType', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterBranchId', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterUser', '');
    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterUserName', '');
    if(is_numeric($clientCompanyId)){
        $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterClientAccount', $clientCompanyId);

        $checkUser =true;

    }else{
        $business_type_id = str_replace('type_','',$clientCompanyId);
        $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterBusinessType', $business_type_id);
        if(is_numeric($userId)){
            $checkUser =true;
        }else{
            if($userId=='user'){
                if($this->uri->segment(5)=='company'){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterAccountsType', 'company');
                    
                }else{
                    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterAccountsType', 'branch');
                    $branch_id = str_replace('branch_','',$this->uri->segment(5));
                    
                    if($branch_id==0){
                        $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterBranchName', 'Main Branch');

                    }else{
                        $branch = $this->em->find('models\Branches', $branch_id);
                        $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterBranchName', $branch->getBranchName());
                    }
                    $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterBranchId', $branch_id);
                    
                }
            }
            $statusId =$this->uri->segment(6);

        }

    }

    if($checkUser){
        $statsUser = $this->em->find('\models\Accounts', $userId);
        $statsCompanyId = $statsUser->getCompany()->getCompanyId();

        $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterUser', $userId);
        $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterUserName', $statsUser->getFullName());
        $statusId = $this->uri->segment(5);
    }

   

    if($statusId){
        if(is_numeric($statusId)){
            $status = $this->em->find('\models\Status', $statusId);
            $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterStatusId', $statusId);
            $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterStatusNameShow', $status->getText());
            $this->session->set_userdata('pSold', '');
        }else{
            if($statusId=='won'){
                $this->session->set_userdata('pWon', 1);
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilterStatusName', $statusId);
        }
    }

$this->session->set_userdata('pStatsFilter', 1);

    $this->index();
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in nginx’s error log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728010/nginx-codeigniter-502-bad-gateway check this thread also.

Comment: 502 Bad gateway is a socket issue ! there must be a kind of errors in the log file, can you please share the content of log files

Comment: `ERROR - 2020-12-15 07:48:26 --> ErrorException [ 2 ]: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given ~ /var/www/vhosts/itsabacus.net/pavementlayers.itsabacus.net/application/views/templates/prospects/table/filters-new.php [ 487 ]`

   this is the error log